# Custom Web control in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web, user-controls

I have created a custom web control which consist of a DropDownList and a TextBox. Custom control is rendering in the web page properly but the value selected in the DropDownList or entered in the TextBox are not getting in the code behind.

Here is my code:

```
public class DropDownListWithTextBox : WebControl
{
  private DropDownList dropDownList;    
  private TextBox textBox;
  protected override void CreateChildControls()
  {
        base.CreateChildControls();

        this.dropDownList = new DropDownList();
        this.dropDownList.ID = this.ID; 
        this.dropDownList.Width = 205;
        foreach (ChoiceInfo choice in this.Choices)
        {
            string ctext = string.Format("{0}: {1}", choice.Text, choice.Value);
            ListItem item = new ListItem(ctext, choice.Value);
            item.Selected = choice.Selected;
            this.dropDownList.Items.Add(item);
        }

        this.dropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Other", "Other"));

        this.textBox = new TextBox();
        this.textBox.ID = this.ID + "_ddlTextBox";
        this.textBox.Width = 200;

        this.Controls.Add(this.dropDownList);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox);
    }
}
```

Control is rendering in the web page properly but the value selected in the ddl or textbox not bale to access in code behind.
Could you please help me to access those value in code behind.

```
case FieldType.DropDownListWithTextBox:

    DropDownListWithTextBox ddl1 = (DropDownListWithTextBox)table.FindControl(field.Name);

    properties.Add(new FeatureProperty(field.Name, ddl1.controlValue()));
 break;
```